# Sorting values in dataframe by order of values in another dataframe R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I would like to sort values in columns of the `xy1` dataframe, based on the increasing order of values in columns of the `xy` dataframe.

```
x <- c(3,1,7,45,22,2)
y <- c(23,65,1,23,2,11)
xy <- data.frame(x,y)

x1 <- c(0.34,0.3,0.7,0.22,0.67,0.87)
y1 <- c(0.4,0.13,0.17,0.72,0.61,0.7)
xy1 <- data.frame(x1,y1)

    > xy
       x  y
    1  3 23
    2  1 65
    3  7  1
    4 45 23
    5 22  2
    6  2 11
    > xy1
        x1   y1
    1 0.34 0.40
    2 0.30 0.13
    3 0.70 0.17
    4 0.22 0.72
    5 0.67 0.61
    6 0.87 0.70
```

The following is a new data.frame result that I desire - note it deals with repeated observations (two the same values in `y`). `x1` and `y1` are now sorted according to the order of values in each column of `xy` dataframe.

```
    x1   y1
1 0.30 0.17
2 0.87 0.61
3 0.34 0.70
4 0.70 0.40
5 0.67 0.72
6 0.22 0.13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `order` function to get the sorting order of a vector.

```
x <- c(3,1,7,45,22,2)
y <- c(23,65,1,23,2,11)
xy <- data.frame(x,y)

x1 <- c(0.34,0.3,0.7,0.22,0.67,0.87)
y1 <- c(0.4,0.13,0.17,0.72,0.61,0.7)
xy1 <- data.frame(x1,y1)

result <- data.frame(x1[order(x)], y1[order(y)])
result
```

This produces

```
  x1.order.x.. y1.order.y..
1         0.30         0.17
2         0.87         0.61
3         0.34         0.70
4         0.70         0.40
5         0.67         0.72
6         0.22         0.13
```

You can beautify the output by setting the column names in the result:

```
data.frame(x1=x1[order(x)], y1=y1[order(y)])
```

Now if you don't want to manually type in everything but have two data frames with the same dimensions that you can use this one-liner

```
 sapply(1:ncol(xy1), function(i) {xy1[order(xy[,i]), i]})
```

which produces

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.30 0.17
[2,] 0.87 0.61
[3,] 0.34 0.70
[4,] 0.70 0.40
[5,] 0.67 0.72
[6,] 0.22 0.13
```

Answer (score 2):

As this is based on `order`ing corresponding columns on both datasets, `Map` can be used

```
xy1[] <- Map(function(x,y) x[order(y)], xy1, xy)
xy1
#    x1   y1
#1 0.30 0.17
#2 0.87 0.61
#3 0.34 0.70
#4 0.70 0.40
#5 0.67 0.72
#6 0.22 0.13
```

---

Or another option is to `order` based on the `col` of 'xy', 'xy'

```
xy1[] <- as.matrix(xy1)[order(col(xy), xy)]
xy1
#    x1   y1
#1 0.30 0.17
#2 0.87 0.61
#3 0.34 0.70
#4 0.70 0.40
#5 0.67 0.72
#6 0.22 0.13
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 <- xy %>% 
  bind_cols(xy1) %>% 
  arrange(x) %>% 
  select(x1)

df_2 <- xy %>% 
  bind_cols(xy1) %>% 
  arrange(y) %>% 
  select(y1)

df <- bind_cols(df_1, df_2)
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
     x1    y1
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.30  0.17
2  0.87  0.61
3  0.34  0.70
4  0.70  0.40
5  0.67  0.72
6  0.22  0.13
```

Basically just arrange `x1` and `y1` by `x` and `y` separately, then combine `x1` and `y1`.